# KDE Plasma: tooltips appear under the mouse cursor

Tags: plasma5

Is there a way to configure tooltips to *not* be obscured by the mouse cursor? First time I'm bothered by this behavior in a window manager:

[image: Plasma tooltips behind mouse cursor]

It happened with the default cursor, and changing the mouse cursor theme didn't help. Happens with all apps, not just LibreOffice.

Plasma 5.18.5 on Kubuntu 20.4 (because it's LTS, otherwise I'd use the newest Plasma). Not sure if I should file this as a [bug](https://bugs.kde.org)?